# Property 'confirmed' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: javascript, firebase, angular5, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have written a function to check if a field exist in a document in cloud firestore to display the data, if not it should not display the data. It does display the data but am getting this error `error TS2339: Property 'confirmed' does not exist on type '{}'.`

```
dataCollection: any;
data: Observable<MycollectionDoc[]>
activatedUsers: any[];

constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedUsers = [];
    let x = this.afs.collection('mycollection').valueChanges();
    x.forEach(element => {
        element.forEach(elem => {
            console.log('My element', elem);
            if (elem.confirmed) {

                this.activatedUsers.push(elem);
                console.log(elem)
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript does not know what type `element` is, so it complains.

Try replacing `if (elem.confirmed)` with `if (elem.hasOwnProperty('confirmed'))`

Comment: I I tried this to pass confirmed:false items with this if (!elem.hasOwnProperty('confirmed')) with this It shows me the same list

Comment: That's correct, because those elements have the `confirmed` property (set to `false`). If you want to check which elements have `confirmed = false`, you can use `if(!elem.confirmed)`

Comment: That works but I run in the error of "error TS2339: Property 'confirmed' does not exist on type '{}'"

Comment: Sorry your right, that was the initial problem. Easily fixable with `if(!elem['confirmed'])`